idx: The emulator will be reloaded and the files will be closed
Lately I've been using idx instead of other editors like VScode and it works great but it happens several times a day that unfortunately the emulators restart and the files you have open are closed and you have to open them again Open!
Of course, the information is not lost and does not cause any problems, but since this happens several times a day, it is annoying.
Is there a solution to this issue?
I also deleted dev.nix and created it again, but it didn't help.
This happens in smaller projects as well.

I think I have it resolved, i don't know if it will work for you too but what I did is I removed the user in chrome where I am signed in and then signed in again.
Same step might work if you clear your cache though I haven't tried it yet.
It stops on auto reloading now, at least for my case.
